# Using #define (preprocessor values) from a C/H file in IAR linker script (.icf)

Tags: c, linker, include, iar, linker-scripts

I need the usage of a certain #define value from a header into an icf file. Consider this,

I have a line in a certain header file like this. #define LINKER_VALUE 0

If this LINKER_VALUE changes to 1, I have to do certain modifications in the icf file. But the visibility if this LINKER_VALUE does not seen in the linker script file.

I have tried to include the header file from the script like this => include "example.h";

This successfully included the header file but it results in lot of errors. ( as it expects that header file to behave like a icf file )

Is there any way to see LINKER_VALUE in the icf file? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can insert C headers directly in icf files. Why do you need it? Can you use *Defined symbols* (#define tab) or *Configuration file symbol definitions* (Config tab) in project linker settings instead?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using CMake for my projects.

Adapting to your question, on the "CMakeLists.txt", I use:

```
set(CMAKE_LINKER_VALUE 1)

configure_file(example.h.in example.h)
configure_file(config.icf.in config.icf)
```

So CMake propagates the configurations for headers and linker configurations.

Next, on the "example.h.in" header, the `LINKER_VALUE` becomes globally visible to the application:

```
#pragma once
#define LINKER_VALUE @CMAKE_LINKER_VALUE@
```

And finally, on the "config.icf.in" linker configuration file, the same value is passed so the configuration change accordingly to certain needs. For example:

```
define symbol LINKER_VALUE @CMAKE_LINKER_VALUE@
if (LINKER_VALUE > 0)
{
  /* specific configuration for this setup */
}
```

The [CMake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/) explains in detail how to use `configure_file()`.

The [IAR tutorial](https://github.com/iarsystems/cmake-tutorial/) explains how to build a CMake project.